# How to convert time data which saved as integer type in csv file into datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, time, datetime-conversion

I have csv file and in 'Time' column,  time data is saved in integer type like

```
7
20
132
4321
123456
...
```

and I have to convert datatime in python like

```
00:00:07
00:00:20
00:01:32
00:43:21
12:34:56
...
```

and size of data is almost 250,000,,,

How do I convert this number to a datetime?

I tried but failed

```
change_time=str(int(df_NPA_2020['TIME'])).zfill(6)
change_time=change_time[:2]+":"+change_time[2:4]+":"+change_time[4:]
change_time
```

and

```
change_time=df_NPA_2020['ch_time'] = df_NPA_2020['TIME'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(str(x), format='%H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You have to use `.astype(str)` method to convert a column as string and not `str(df_NPA_2020['TIME'])`. The latter is like a `print`.

```
df_NPA_2020['ch_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_NPA_2020['TIME'].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.time
print(df_NPA_2020)

# Output
     TIME             ch_time
0       7 1900-01-01 00:00:07
1      20 1900-01-01 00:00:20
2     132 1900-01-01 00:01:32
3    4321 1900-01-01 00:43:21
4  123456 1900-01-01 12:34:56
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse the number into a datetime, then format it:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([7,20,132,4321,123456], columns=['Time'])
print(df)
df.Time = df.Time.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(f'{x:06}', format='%H%M%S')).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Time
0       7
1      20
2     132
3    4321
4  123456
       Time
0  00:00:07
1  00:00:20
2  00:01:32
3  00:43:21
4  12:34:56
```